Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir while using yarn
I'm getting this error while installing using yarn add

solve the error generated while installing using webpack with yarn workspaces

warning "workspace-aggregator-904fa3eb-13dd-488a-bb79-3257c1219256 > @package/webapp > ts-loader@9.5.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^5.0.0".
error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir


Don't work in cloud directory. OneDrive can cause such problems. Move the project to a different directory and try it again.
